# Using make with msysgit

Tags: makefile, msysgit

I'm using msysgit on Windows 7, but it doesn't seem to come with make. Is there an easy way to get make running on msysgit?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a [link to `make.exe`](http://repo.or.cz/w/msysgit.git?a=blob;f=bin/make.exe;h=a971ea1266ff40e89137bba068e2c944a382725f;hb=968336eddac1874c56cd934d10783566af5a3e26) in the msysgit Google code [issues section](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=278). I downloaded it and put it in `Git\bin` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Unbelievable how deep-LOST is this info, poor Windows users. It's good to mention that you'll probably want to rename it to 'make' instead of `bin_make`, so you can type just `make` in your terminal - like you always do?

Answer (score 2):

Suprisingly, by using MSYS itself, or MinGW if you need the GCC compiler - see http://www.mingw.org or better http://tdragon.net/recentgcc.

Answer (score 2):

did  you try the netinstall ? 
It does come with make.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the `msys.bat` and `initialize.sh` step still needed to be performed.

The 'Full installer' isn't. It only gets you a minimum, and you then have to get it to do the remaining download - see [MSysGit:InstallMSysGit](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/MSysGit%3aInstallMSysGit). I just updated the wiki to highlight the steps I'd missed!

The Net Installer is a much better option as it is able to run through almost all the steps for you, downloading and compiling the latest version automatically. Once you have done so, have a look for the various `release.sh` files.

It can be a nervous first step choosing the right course of action - I'm only a few steps ahead, and still cautious.