# git pull from repository to server

Tags: git

I'm currently using a file on my mac to pull from a (bitbucket) repository to the server.
The file looks like this (it's a `makefile`):

```
PUB_DIR="the/path/to/my/relevant/files"

server-pull:
    @ssh -t myusername@server "cd ${PUB_DIR}; git pull"
```

I can simply perform that action by calling `make server-pull` in the terminal.
What I'd like to know is how to adapt this for windows, so  I can call the function the same way through the command line tool like on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use the very same script: msysgit comes with Cygwin/MSYS, so you can execute shell scripts there too. Just fire up a Git shell.

The other way is to simply create a batch file (or a PowerShell script, just be prepared to add ssh to the path etc.), but I think using the same script in every environment has a huge advantage.

If you want to stick with make, [here's a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219926/using-make-with-msysgit) about how to set it up for the Git shell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd like to continue with the same script as you mentioned with make. Could you add to you answer how to rename it to `make` instead of `bin_make` since that isn't described in the mentioned thread? Also when copying the .exe file to the bin folder I can't call it through the command line tool with `git bin-make`. Anything else to do?

Comment: Have you restarted the session? Btw this does not seem that trivial but based on what Google says a few guys has made that. In your case, I'd drop the makefile and create a simple bash script for that, that can be used in both environments.

Comment: I've restarted it, yes. But anyway could you give me a hint how this bash file would have to look like on windows? I've a very very basic knowledge of bash scripts...

Comment: Same as on Linux :-) Just call it within a git shell (you have to install git anyway for git pull so you'll have it there). It comes with a miminal "Linux shell" (MinGW == Minimalist GNU for Windows).

Comment: That did it for me after installing OpenSSH:
`@echo off
set PUB_DIR=the/path/to/my/relevant/files
@ssh -t www-data@myusername "cd %PUB_DIR%; git pull"`
Thank you!